# using 'sed' to trim HTMl tags and unnecessary whitespace

Tags: regex, sed

so i was looking for a Sed command that extracts HTML tags (without attributes or nested tags) from a text. the text should be converted as follows:

```
<h1>This is a valid HTML tag</h1>.
<i>These</b> <1>invalid</i> <a}>tags</a}> should be ignored.
```

Becomes:

```
This is a valid HTML tag.
<i>These</b> <1>invalid</i> <a}>tags</a}> should be ignored.
```

I tried this command `sed 's/^.*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/'` but it is not completely correct :(

and a sed expression to trim unnecessary white space [space or tab] from the start and
the end of a string.

Thanks in advance!
:)

Comment: I am a complete noob when it comes to this and i was hoping to get to know commands like 'grep' and 'sed' better :) but thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: To emphasize @LutzHorn's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Comment: If you want to learn `sed`, `grep`, or `awk`, don't use HTML or XML as your learning material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by some people, HTML is not a good candidate for regexp.

Nevertheless, this one may be a starting point (tested in vim)

```
:%s:<\([^>]*\)>\(.*\)</\1>:\2:
```